# I get "There is no OpenGL context current in the current thread." for glViewport() while other GL Static Methods Work

Tags: java, opengl

I am porting a C++ OpenGL GLFW engine to Java and I get the "No Context Current" error when I run glViewport() from the Window Size Callback. How do I fix this? Here is my code.

Init:

```
private void init() {
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = errorCallbackPrint(System.err));

        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW!");
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); 
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); 
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); 

        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, FULLSCREEN, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create GLFW window!");
        }

        ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - width) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - height) / 2);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, windowSizeCallback = GLFWWindowSizeCallback(this::windowSizeCallback));
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = GLFWKeyCallback(this::keyCallback));
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseButtonCallback = GLFWMouseButtonCallback(this::mouseButtonCallback));
        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursorPosCallback = GLFWCursorPosCallback(this::cursorPosCallback));
        glfwSwapInterval(VSYNC);
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        GLContext.createFromCurrent();

        System.out.println("GLFW Version: " + glfwGetVersionString());
        System.out.println("OpenGL Version: " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    }
```

Here is the update method:

```
public void update() {
        int error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) System.err.println("OpenGL Error: " + error);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
```

Everything there seems fine but IDK.

Finally, here is the Window Size Callback method:

```
private void windowSizeCallback(long window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Edit: Oh, also I want to note that the error comes from the glViewport() method call.

Comment: I'd guess your windowSizeCallback is not being called form the thread you made your context current in (glfwPollEvents). According to http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html : "On some platforms, certain events are sent directly to the application without going through the event queue, causing callbacks to be called outside of a call to one of the event processing functions." Maybe this is the problem? PS: I have never actually used glfw

Comment: Hmm, if that is the case then I'm not sure what to do since it is a lot more efficient to set the Viewport only on resize, than it is to set it constantly.

Comment: Simply make a boolean flag that says "Hey you need to redo the viewport" and read it out in your main thread. Make sure its volatile, just in case. That way you still only do it once, but you do it a bit later. So in your windowSizeCallback do "FLAG = true" then in main do "if (FLAG) {FLAG = false, glViewport(...)}

Comment: Yeah I know I could do that. But every operation counts and I rather not have a constant if every loop (yeah I know it doesn't really do anything), but I am a huge efficiency freak so yeah. I did end up finding out that the callback was being called before the window was visible, so I just moved the line down when I made the window visible. Thanks though.

Comment: I actually thought about commenting that, but then I saw your glfwMakeContextCurrent which, in the spec, mentions nothing about a hidden window. Neither does glfwShowWindow tell anything about contexts. That's annoying.